# Is it possible to use .Net Standard System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings with an appSettings.json file

Tags: appsettings, .net-standard-2.0, system.configuration

I would like to be able to build .Net Standard libraries that can retrieve their own configuration information whether they are called from a Net Framework or a Net Core application.

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager has been added to Net Standard. I have proven that I can use this to pull from a traditional app or web.config file such as this:

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testString"];

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="testString" value="xxwx"/>
    <add key="testInt" value="234"/>
    <add key="testBool" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

I would like to be able to pull the same value using the same code from an appettings.json file. Something like the following:

```
{
  "appSettings": [
    {
      "Key": "testString",
      "Value": "xxwx"
    },
    {
      "Key": "testInt",
      "Value": "234"
    },
    {
      "Key": "testBool",
      "Value": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is possible using System.Configuration from Net Standard 2.0 to read an appSettings.json file? The real purpose here is that I do not want to have consuming applications have a need to understand configuration parameters of libraries. I also want to be able to use the same libraries from Net Framework and Net Core applications. Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: RE: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager has been added to Net Standard. I have proven that I can use this to pull from a traditional app or web.config file` - this incorrect: `System.Configuration` is not part of .NET Standard (as of 2.1). If you were able to compile and "prove", then you most likely had referenced an implementation from somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, that functionality is provided by `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, [which is compatible with .NETStandard 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/).

You can see an example of loading the configuration here:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
     .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
     .AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

This will load an `appsettings.json` file as well as an environment specific app settings file (ex: `appsettings.Production.json`).

To get the settings, you can see more about it in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration).

Comment: What I initially wanted was to be able to write to an app / web config in net framework apps while writing to json config for core apps. The purpose was so that I could write helpers for DLLs that could do their own configuration and work with both framework and core. What I realized is that I can use a separate config file and I do not need to concern myself with writing to the app / web config. So this will work for me.