# How to add a .NET Framework assembly reference to a .NET Standard 2.0 project?

Tags: .net, .net-standard, .net-4.8

I'm beginning the arduous and long-running project of converting all of my internal-use packages from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET Standard 2.0. It'll be a pay-as-you-go effort that'll probably wrap up near the end of this year.

Anyway, I've already hit my first stumbling block. I'm trying to add an assembly reference `System.Configuration` to my new .NET Standard project. Here's the project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>Intexx.Configuration</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Intexx.Core" Version="2020.8.24.1">
      <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
    </PackageReference>
    
    <PackageReference Include="itxcorlib" Version="2021.7.19.1">
      <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net48' ">
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The multi-targeting configuration is based on information I found in [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/22/MultiTargeting-and-Porting-a-NET-Library-to-NET-Core-20). I also found lots of info on referencing a .NET Standard assembly from a .NET Framework project, but not the other way 'round.

Here's some of the code (that works in a .NET Framework project):

```vbnet
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Intexx.Linq

Public Class Config
  Public Shared ReadOnly Property Environment As Environments
    Get
      If Not Enums(Of Environments).TryGetValue(Settings(ENV), Environment, SearchBy.Name) Then
        Environment = Environments.None
      End If
    End Get
  End Property

  Private Shared Property Settings(Key As String) As String
    Get
      With ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        If Not .AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys.Contains(Key) Then
          .AppSettings.Settings.Add(Key, Environments.Dev.ToString)
          .Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
        End If

        Return .AppSettings.Settings(Key).Value
      End With
    End Get
    Set(Value As String)
      With ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        If .AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys.Contains(Key) Then
          .AppSettings.Settings(Key).Value = Value
        Else
          .AppSettings.Settings.Add(Key, Value)
        End If

        .Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
      End With
    End Set
  End Property

  Private Const ENV As String = "Environment"
End Class
```

As we can see here, I've imported the `System.Configuration` namespace, but I'm getting this error for each call to `ConfigurationManager` in the code:

> `ConfigurationManager` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

This is strange, since IntelliSense is working:

[image]

I see it reports 'Not Available' for `netstandard2.0`. Does this mean that I won't be able to use .NET Standard for projects that need to reference `System.Configuration` (and potentially other .NET Framework assemblies)? I hope not. I need to use these packages as I slowly migrate to .NET 5/6.

I tried referencing the assembly by its full path, but that didn't help.

How can I add this assembly reference so that I can use it in my .NET Standard project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197579/is-it-possible-to-use-net-standard-system-configuration-configurationmanager-ap

Comment: That's a potential hit, but it seems to be targeted for use in an ASP.NET project, not a library project. Also, it seems to support only `json`-based config files. I need something that supports `App.config`, in the way that `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` does. Am I missing something here?

Comment: On second thought, I might be able to use this. I'll fiddle with it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: In the end, I decided to take a different approach altogether. Thanks to the link you provided, which provoked further thought, I'll use a separate `json` file for these settings. From there I'll just Newtonsoft it all together.